# Rails impossible to get post response in rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, middleware

I made a rails 3 rack middleware to log users actions with `request = Rack::Request.new(env)`.

So i send to my database the `request.fullpath` and `request.user_agent`, as detailed below:

My issue appears I want to get the POST response too (to get ids, people name extracted from the JSON payload ...).

So i get the `response = Rack::Response.new(request.path)`. But when i print `response.body`, i have only my `request.path`, and the `request.params` does not contain anything ...

By looking at the response with Firebug, I can see all the data I want.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved  !

I finally add `status, headers, body = @app.call(env)` to my middleware and send the `body` variable to my service. For each POST request, `body` contains all the post response I want.

Comment: Finally!! this is the answer that July(Joselito) is looking for. Thank you so much he can now go home.